# php restore_error_handler not work as expected

Tags: php, error-handling

```
error_reporting(-1);

set_error_handler(function ($level, $message, $file = '', $line = 0) {
   echo '1--------------NOTICE or WARNING';
});

set_error_handler(function ($level, $message, $file = '', $line = 0) {
   echo '2--------------NOTICE or WARNING';

   set_error_handler(function($level, $message, $file = '', $line = 0) {
       echo '3--------Handler';
   });
   restore_error_handler();
});

$arr = [];
var_dump($arr["a"]);
var_dump($arr["b"]);
```

output:

```
2--------------NOTICE or WARNINGNULL
1--------------NOTICE or WARNINGNULL
```

phpversion : 7.0.10

As the output above, it seems the `restore_error_handler` in a handler doesn't work as usual.

I expect the `error_handler` go to 2, but the `error_handler` go back to 1.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird, but it does not seems to work with callback function. I have no clue why. Still, this works:

```
function foo1() {echo "<br>1<br>";}
function foo2() {echo "<br>2<br>"; restore_error_handler();}
function foo3() {echo "<br>3<br>"; restore_error_handler();}

set_error_handler("foo1");    //current error handler: foo1
set_error_handler("foo2");    //current error handler: foo2
set_error_handler("foo3");    //current error handler: foo3

$arr = [];
var_dump($arr["a"]);
var_dump($arr["b"]);
var_dump($arr["c"]);
```

Display:

> 3
>
> NULL
>
> 2
>
> NULL
>
> 1
>
> NULL

Comment: if you add a `set_error_handler` to foo3. like `function foo3() {echo "<br>3<br>"; set_error_handler(function(){echo 'XXX';}); restore_error_handler();}`   you will get a output of `3 2` 。this is the same as the problem in my question. -(